# Img from database

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have post where i get content from database. In that content are images, like this:

```
<h1>Heading 1</h1> 
{{ HTML::image('images/export-html.png', $alt = "export to html package") }}
<p>Some content. This all is copied in database column</p>
```

But i don't get them in my post.
In post code is like this, for example:

```
@section('content')
    {{ $htmltablepost->bigdescription }}

@stop
```

In this code I get all content like i need, except images. If i try to get them like this:

```
@section('content')
    {{ $htmltablepost->bigdescription }}

    {{ HTML::image('images/export-html.png', $alt = "export to html package") }}
@stop
```

Then I get image from second line after section line. Where is problem?

Comment: That is what i think too. I dont. They are in my server folder just. It means, that i need them in database too to load?

Comment: sory, i write on your coment

Comment: No. In content field you have "<h1>Heading 1</h1> 
{{ HTML::image('images/export-html.png', $alt = "export to html package") }}
<p>Some content. This all is copied in database column</p>" ?

Comment: You mean, when webpage load, did i get right content from db? Answer - yes, except images

Comment: {{ HTML::image('images/export-html.png', $alt = "export to html package") }} is from db or not?

Comment: No. It is to check if works. It is not from db. It is copy paste from db content, but it is written for me, to check if syntax is correct, and it is because image appear there.

Comment: What is your post content in db?

Comment: Think about it. I have 2 lines in section. 
 
both of them are the same. One line is text from database, but second line is just text. From db - text isn't working. Second text is working

Comment: Content in db - in my first code example.

Comment: I think that problem is in "echo" your image. What you get in source (ctrl+U) in this line: {{ HTML::image('images/export-html.png', $alt = "export to html package") }} ?

Comment: Is no option to change {{ HTML::image('images/export-html.png', $alt = "export to html package") }} to <img src='images/export-html.png alt="export to html package"> ?

Comment: That wont work too :( . and i edit your line with ' after png .

Comment: Could you test <img> with full path to image?

Comment: That you must checks different paths (check first '/images/export-html.png' ) with <img>